# testNg is ignoring parameterized tests with dataProvider | Maven | IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, testng, dataprovider

I am trying to run a parameterized test in testNg using dataProvider. But somehow it is always ignoring that test case. Below is the reference code:

```
@DataProvider(name = "test")
public Object[][] testDP() throws Exception {
    Object[][] arrayObject = getExcelData("TestData.xlsx", "TestData", "testName");
    return arrayObject;
}


@Test(dataProvider = "test", groups = {"sanity"})
public void testMethod(String testName, String logisticsHandler) {
    System.out.print(testName + "\n");
    setUpdateLogisticsHandler(logisticsHandler);
    updateLogisticsHandler(context.getAuthToken(),context.getQuoteIdForRfq());

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the arrayObject content?

Comment: `testName                         logisticsHandler
logistics_OFB                 OFB
logistics_ SUPPLIER SUPPLIER
logistics_BUYER         BUYER`

Comment: What if you skip `getExcelData` and replace it by a static array for the moment? How do you run your test? What is the used command and surefire configuration?

Comment: Will do it with static array. And update you.. ...... Surefire version is 2.19.1 .. And I am not running through mvn command but generally running that test in intelliJ. And surefire config looks like this - >                                                           <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>sanitySuite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of sending data to the test.

1. Static Arrays usage - as suggested by Julien Herr
2. If you are using the excel to get the data then in excel you must have exactly same number of rows/fields as in the @test function.

For Example: String testName, String logisticsHandler are two fields in your @test function then the excel must have ONLY two rows with the required fields testdata so that the ObjectArray will have these fields.

You can use Apache POI and handle this very easily.

Comment: Thanks sai... Will try it. Also i read an article that there is some issue with the combination of testNG and Maven, while using dataProvider of testNG. Will try to figure that out. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening as i see the name is different

```
  @Test(dataProvider = "test", groups = {"sanity"})
```

in the above line you should give the dataProvider as **testDP** instead of **test** the name of the function

```
  @Test(dataProvider = "testDP", groups = {"sanity"})
```

testDP is providing data to your test and no function named as test

The above thing should solve the problem. Also the name can be removed from dataprovider to avoid any confusion

```
  @DataProvider(name = "test")
```